# How to find patterns of data in noise from compass sensor in iphone

Tags: javascript, algorithm, machine-learning, pattern-recognition, magnetometer

I am playing with the iphone compass sensor in html5 as shown in this jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/ZuPYM/

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(e) {
        // y-axis - yaw
        var g = e.gamma || 0;
        // x-axis - tilt
        var b = e.beta || 0;
        // z=axis - swivel
        var a = e.alpha || 0;
```

My question is the data coming back seems to be constantly fluctuating and I would be interested to know if various devices cause changes in these fluctuations.

Say I start off getting the compass data, and then I plug in my macbook charger/transformer (which would produce it's own magnetic field) near my phone with the compass inside.
Is there a way to algorithmically isolate these new fluctuations from the background noise? A bit like isolating a bass line from a music track.

Any recommendations on further reading or the topics I should google are much appreciated. I'm not sure whether this is a task for machine learning. At the moment I'm at a bit of a loss what to search for.

Thanks!

## update

It's just been pointed out that the code above is for the orientation sensor, not the magnetometer in the iphone.
The code for the magnetometer would be this part :

// degree north
var c = e.compassHeading || e.webkitCompassHeading || 0;

which doesn't fluctuate at all. So this question is somewhat a false premise, but the core question still stands - how to get data out of noisy data.

Comment: that's not a compass, that's orientation sensor code you show. without a 2nd input, you have no way to isolate interference and correct. you can divide the numbers into smaller integers to quiet down the noise, or put in a trap that needs a shift of 5 or more to do something...

Comment: Good point, added in to question, sort of makes original question obsolete. But I'm still curious, is there no way of doing it without a second sensor -  presampling the data and then finding out level of fluctuation and looking for vareints in a live stream?

Comment: the problem is not that there's no way, the problem is that there's lots of ways to do it, but they all depend on specific task goals and data usages. many noise-related image filters might be worth reviewing (median, blur, salt+pepper, etc) as the basic concepts can also be applied to linear streams instead of 2d maps; just pretend you have a 1x100 image. you can also do really simple stuff like adding the last reading and the current reading and dividing by 2 to cut spikes in half. in short, there's lots of algos, but it depends on what you're trying to do in terms of picking one out to use.